# Is there any kubernetes agent in Tekton pipeline similar to Jenkins Agent

Tags: jenkins, openshift, tekton

I am new to Tekton pipeline. I am migrating Jenkins file from Tekton pipeline

I do have the follow jenkinsfile codes

```
pipeline {
libraries {
lib 'operator-pipeline-library'
}
parameters {
string(name: 'OPERATOR_CATALOG_REPO', description: ' operator images that are in the catalog', defaultValue: 'operator-3rdparty-dev-local.net')
string(name: 'OPERATOR_INDEX', description: 'Artifactory ', defaultValue: 'operator-3rdparty-catalog-dev-local.net')
}
agent {
kubernetes {
cloud 'openshift'
yamlFile 'operator-mirror-pod.yaml'
}
}
}
```

I do want to know how do I re-write the following

```
agent {
kubernetes {
cloud 'openshift'
yamlFile 'operator-pod.yaml'
}
}
```

in Tekton pipelines

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to do something with Tekton, the first thing I would recommend checking is the Tekton Catalog. They have a GitHub repository.

In your case, they have the [openshift-client](https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/main/task/openshift-client/0.2/openshift-client.yaml) task that could be useful.

Depending on how your Jenkins was configured, you may have to reproduce its credentials configuration as Kubernetes Secrets - or executing commands against local cluster, make sure your PipelineRun uses a ServiceAccount with enough privileges to create objects.

As a more generic answer: how do I translate Jenkins groovy into Tekton: you don't. You rewrite everything from scratch. And while it may be the beginning of a long road: at the end of it, you're done with groovy. You can script in python, ruby, shell, whatever runtime you have in your pods. All of which would be better options, in terms of performance, maintenance, ...